# How to insert rows for each of the type column?

Tags: mysql, query, insert

How to insert rows for each of the type column? If there is two type, type 1 and type 2, then I need to insert two rows and also need to change the order and id value for whole table.

**current status:**

**CHOICE** Table

```
id  choice  type    order
1    AA      1       1
2    BB      1       2
3    CC      1       3
4    AAA     2       4
5    BBB     2       5
6    CCC     2       6
7    DDD     2       7
```

**Required updated table:**
Now i wan to insert choice "000"  for each type. The updated table will be look like bellow.  How can I achieve this?

updated  **CHOICE** Table

```
id  choice  type    order
1    000     1       1
2    AA      1       2
3    BB      1       3
4    CC      1       4
5    000     2       5
6    AAA     2       6
7    BBB     2       7
8    CCC     2       8
9    DDD     2       9
```

here, id and order column serialized again.

The actual table is too big, so I cannot insert by edit. Please help for this complex query. I have no clue to solve this.

Comment: What are the real rules for ordering the output?  Based on your example, `ORDER BY type, choice` works perfectly.  If that is not adequate, please change your example to have a row that violates that `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely *do not* want to change the id for *any* row when inserting new data.

Your Primary Key (id) value should be set when each record is created, remain *the same* throughout the entire lifetime of that record, right up to the point where that record is finally destroyed.
Imagine if banks "renumbered" people's bank accounts every time someone [else] closed their account.  There would be chaos.

If the combination of "choice" and "type" is unique, then that *could* form a Natural, Composite, Primary Key for this table, removing the need for the id column entirely.
YMMV.
Alternatively, just let your database allocate ids to the new records - their actual values *do not matter*, just that they are unique.

I do not believe you need the order column either.  From the data you show ...

```
select 
. . . 
order by type, choice
```

... would achieve exactly the same thing, without the need to update *anything* as data is added or removed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you help me with that how can I achieve the updated table? This table will be modified by truncating the table and inserting all the row again. So I need to serialize both id and order. Thanks.

Comment: If you're removing all the data and reinserting it all again, then your inserting logic should take care of the numbering.  That said, I would still question *why* you are doing this at all!  Forcibly sequential numbers are /not/ the norm in a Relational database. 
Database != Spreadsheet